# How do I create a dataset in C# with local database

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, local-database

I am a beginner in C# and created a database in a Windows Forms App for a customer data, the function of it is to take the user's phone number and then search the table and then if it is found then populate the data fields with the information; otherwise it needs to add the new customer to the table.

When I run the code I get an error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'data  source(localdb)\mssqlocaldb;attachdbfilename'.'

This is my code:

```
    DataTable TableCust;
    SqlConnection cnCust;
    SqlDataAdapter dataCust;
    DataGrid dtGridCust;
    public bool buttonClicked = false;
    private static int CurrentOrder = 1000;
    private int i = 0;
    Validation v = new Validation();

    public frmPizzaPetes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string dataSource;
    string SqlParms;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnAccept.Enabled = false;
        lblOrderNo.Text = CurrentOrder.ToString();
        Price();
        //
        dataSource = @"Data Source(LocalDB)\MSSQLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|C:\Users\tyada\DATABASE\Pizza.mdf;";
        SqlParms = "Integrated Securtiy=True; Connect Timeout==30";
        string SqlCust = "select * from Customers";
        string strConn = dataSource + SqlParms;
        cnCust = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        cnCust.Open();
        TableCust = new DataTable();
        dtGridCust.DataSource = TableCust;
    }

 public bool ifCustIsFound()
    {
        bool tester=false;
        string SqlCustomer = "SELECT*FROM Customers WHERE CustPhone= '" + mtbPhone.Text + "';";
        dataCust = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCustomer, cnCust);
        dataCust.Fill(TableCust);

        if (TableCust.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            txtName.Text = TableCust.Rows[0]["CustName"].ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = TableCust.Rows[0]["CustAddress"].ToString();
            txtApt.Text = TableCust.Rows[0]["CustSuite"].ToString();
            txtCity.Text = TableCust.Rows[0]["CustCity"].ToString();
            mtbZip.Text = TableCust.Rows[0]["CustZip"].ToString();
            cboState.Text = TableCust.Rows[0]["CustState"].ToString();
           // dtGridCust.DataSource = TableCust;
        }


        else
        {
            DialogResult dlg=MessageBox.Show("Add Customer?","Customer not found", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dlg == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                     string strConn = dataSource + SqlParms;
                     SqlDataAdapter adaptSQL = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strConn);
                     SqlCommand cmdCust = new SqlCommand();
                     SqlCommandBuilder cmdBld = new SqlCommandBuilder(adaptSQL);
                     DataRow newCust;
                     newCust = TableCust.NewRow();   
                     newCust["CustPhone"] = mtbPhone.Text;
                     newCust["CustName"] = txtName.Text;
                     newCust["CustAddress1"] = txtAddress.Text;
                     newCust["CustAddress2"] = txtApt.Text;
                     newCust["CustCity"] = txtCity.Text;
                     newCust["CustState"] = cboState.Text;
                     newCust["CustZip"] = mtbZip.Text;
                     try
                     {
                         TableCust.Rows.Add(newCust);  
                         cmdBld.GetUpdateCommand();   
                         adaptSQL.Update(TableCust);
                         MessageBox.Show("Customer Added!");
                     }
                     catch (SqlException)
                     {
                         MessageBox.Show("Customer Add Failed!");
                     }

            } 
            txtName.Focus();

        }

        return tester;
    }
```

Comment: Your connection string is incorrect. What type of db are you trying to connect to exactly?

Comment: a local database, this is actually for a class and my teacher provided a .mdf file download.

Answer (score 0):

it seems "=" is missing in data source. Try this.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnAccept.Enabled = false;
        lblOrderNo.Text = CurrentOrder.ToString();
        Price();
        //
        dataSource = @"Data Source =(LocalDB)\MSSQLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|C:\Users\tyada\DATABASE\Pizza.mdf;";
        SqlParms = "Integrated Securtiy=True; Connect Timeout==30";
        string SqlCust = "select * from Customers";
        string strConn = dataSource + SqlParms;
        cnCust = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        cnCust.Open();
        TableCust = new DataTable();
        dtGridCust.DataSource = TableCust;
    }
```